# Is there a way to use Thymeleaf 2 with Spring Boot 2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Currently I'm upgrading from Spring Boot 1.5 to Spring Boot 2.1.5.
I know the migration guide https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html

But I have some huge Tenant based template in template wrapping mechanism which is strongly relying on IResourceResolver.

As I see here https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/419 this topic was refactored completely.

How can I use Spring Boot 2 with the old thymeleaf 2?

We plan a complete frontend rework in a few months, than I would not use thymeleaf anymore. But I have to upgrade to spring boot 2 because auf some spring security topics.

Comment: same here. guess i'm going to upgrade thymeleaf at the same time ...

Comment: Did you find any workaround to use thymeleaf 2 with spring boot 2?

Comment: unfortunately not